# bxslider does not show images when chrome updated

Tags: jquery, html, bxslider

From yesterday that chrome updated itself `Bxslider` does not show images at first and I should click on next or prev buttons  see the images
Is there any solution ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since when I posted that question the chrome updated with some bugs . All the websites that I coded have error on Chrome . So I got it will relate to new update release of Chrome
But for now Chrome released another update recently and fixed all bugs about loading CSS3 . So all website are working as well now .

About `Bxslider` that had problem it was about this issue and because it coded by CSS3 that time can not load completely